# How can I make it so that the checkbox(when active) changes the color of the background div?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.switch{
  width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -50px;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
.track{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
  background-color: #353b48;
  height: 20px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
.circle{
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #dcdde1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .1s;
}
.checkbox{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: .1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .circle{
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.background_overlay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: .1s;
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .background_overlay{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="checkbox">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="track"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="background_overlay"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I wanna change the color of the div called "background_overlay" when checkbox is :active. The thing is, the background_overlay div is out of the switch div which contains the checkbox. I looked on internet but I can't figure out how to do this, there is no selector for this case. How could I achieve this please?

Comment: This is not possible with HTML and CSS. It is possible with javascript.

Comment: @user1601324 This IS possible, cf. my answer ...

Comment: @Bazaim only because you change the HTML. Lots of things are possible if you change the question :) In the text the questioner directly says "the background_overlay div is out of the switch div which contains the checkbox" and they are correct where they say "there is no selector for this case". It is not possible to select a parent's sibling element in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you where not far away from a solution.

What i've done :

- change `<div class="switch">` into `<label for="bg-switch" class="switch">`
- add `id="bg-switch"` to the checkbox
- change `.checkbox:checked ~ .circle{` to `.checkbox:checked ~ .switch .circle{`

```css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.switch{
  width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -50px;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
.track{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 1px;
  background-color: #353b48;
  height: 20px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
.circle{
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #dcdde1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .1s;
}
.checkbox{
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: .1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .switch .circle{
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.background_overlay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: .1s;
}
.checkbox:checked ~ .background_overlay{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="checkbox" id="bg-switch">
    <checkbox="bg-switch" class="switch">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <div class="track"></div>
    </label>
    <div class="background_overlay"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Edit: It working by using the CSS operator `~` and adding `for` on the `<label>`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes

Comment: Thank you very much! Though could you please explain to me how this works? Is this a property of the <label> ?

Comment: @MaxAnimator Edited

Comment: OOOH! I didn't know about this property of the labels! They're so useful! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a bit, but it seems to be working fine now.

I basically put everything in one div, and centered all the elements in the middle with a bit of fine tuning

Doing it with JavaScript would have made it much easier as you have more control over the DOM

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.switch {
    margin: auto;
}

.track {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 1px;
    background-color: #353b48;
    height: 20px;
    width: 48px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.circle {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-95%, -50%);
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #dcdde1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .1s;
}

.checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: .1s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox:checked~.circle {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.background_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: .1s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+#d2 {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="d1" class="checkbox" />
        <div class="background_overlay" id="d2"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="track"> </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```